# Closing featured questions

Tags: support, vote-to-close, bounty

We are unable to close featured questions. The current one 'evil eye' has nothing to do with Hinduism, but because it is featured, it can't be closed. Why can't we vote to close featured questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Featured questions with bonuses](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/875/featured-questions-with-bonuses)

Answer (score 4):

Not only Hinduism SE, all SE sites have this limitation. This is for "fair use" of bounty.

We should note that one cannot offer bounty until 24 hours after the question was asked. None voted to close this question as off-topic in these two days span.

If you feel this question as off topic, flag the question for moderators attention. Moderators can remove the bounty, close featured question or delete the question. Bounty reputation will be refunded in case of deletion.

Refer [How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14591):

> The moderators have a menu to remove / refund the bounty, so this is no longer an issue. **Flag such things for moderator attention** as the moderators have all the tools necessary to deal with this now.

Refer [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/260388)

> **Why can't I vote to close or migrate a bounty question?**
>
> Bounty questions cannot be closed directly.
>
> However, [diamond moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) can refund bounties, which would then allow it to be closed, migrated, or deleted like any other question. ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/why-cant-we-close-questions-with-bounties/27103#27103))

Related: [Allow users to vote to close bountied questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121448)