# Can moderators refund bounties, change bounty notices etc?

Tags: discussion, moderators, bounty

If there's a typo in the bounty notice and I want to correct it or I want to add more details to the notice besides the standard template, what's the correct procedure do it?

Does one of the mods have to remove the bounty notice & refund the points, then user needs to start a new bounty?

**EDIT**:

Another question: On this site, if bounty is not having the desired effect of attracting more authentic answers, can moderators extend the bounty by one or two weeks? I.e., refund points and have user start a new bounty for another week without losing points or reputation?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Yeah, flag the post and we can refund the bounty so you can make changes and start a new one.  But only make the request if you intend to correct the bounty and start it again, not if you just regret having started the bounty at all, because in that case we're not supposed to refund the bounty.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Ok. Another question: On this site, if bounty is not having the desired effect of attracting more authentic answers, can moderators extend the bounty by one more week? I.e., refund points and have user start a new bounty for another week?

Comment: @sv. No, that's not the kind of thing we're supposed to do.  If you want to extend things from one week to two weeks, you need to spend more reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, moderator can remove bounty notice and refund the bounty.

According to [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/260388)

> - They can (at their discretion) refund and cancel a bounty.

Moderators [can't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252897/4493879) edit the bounty message. So if you really<sup>[1]</sup> need to edit the message then the only way is to flag and ask any moderator as they can remove and refund bounty and then you can start a new one.

<sup>[1]</sup> Note that removing or refunding bounty by moderator is only  carried out in special circumstances i.e., closing, migrating, deleting featured questions etc. So, you are supposed to flag for removal of bounty for exceptional reasons only.

Related feature-request: [Can we have a way to edit bounty custom message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188/260388)

For complete information on bounty system, visit [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/260388)

<sup>(see the related edit to the previous [post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/776/277))</sup>

---

> **EDIT**:
>
> Another question: On this site, if bounty is not having the desired effect of attracting more authentic answers, can moderators extend the bounty by one or two weeks? I.e., refund points and have user start a new bounty for another week without losing points or reputation?

No, moderators are not supposed to do anything in that case and bounty doesn't guarantee a desired effect or response.

From mentioned [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/260388):

> **What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?**
>
> If after the end of the bounty period a question has no answers, no bounty will be awarded and the question will no longer be featured.
>
> Bounties are best understood as exchanging reputation for higher question visibility and increased answerer motivation. A bounty does not **guarantee** a response and is **not refunded** if none are received.

If you want to extend the bounty, you've to apply/start it again with [double amount of reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/260388).

Comment: @sv. Updated the answer.